# How to set an object by a new object and affect to all reference

Tags: c#

I have an object `Component` called A and A have a `List<Component>` Items that contains reference of all `Component` that related to A.

And I also have many derived components like `SupportComponent`, `CommonComponent`.

My question is: Is it possible to make all reference of an object change when I set a reference by new object?

Example

```cs
Component A = new Component("A");
A.Items.Add(new Component("c")); //add c to A
Component c = A.Items[0]; //get component c in A

c = new SupportComponent("c2"); //set c by new object
//my expectation is A.Items[0] would be changed to "c2" instead of "c"
```

Thanks

Comment: You can always wrap the reference in another object, and use that. Regardless of what you do, you'll need one extra layer of indirection to access the object.

Comment: It would be true if you were to change the component c, rather than replacing it. because component c is a local variable, and you're changing it to a new supportcomponent, and thus replacing the reference.

Comment: @Nam Have you tried this? What does `A.Items[0]` show after changing c?

Comment: @ChibuzeOpata Name property of `A.Items[0]` is "c" and Name of `c` is "c2". And I want `A.Items[0]` change too due to in my requirement, a Component would have flexible type.

Comment: `Component c` refers to `A.Items[0]`. This means, if you change some property in `c`, you will change it in `A.Items[0]`.
If you now assign new `SupportComponent("c2")` to `c`, the object where `c` refers to will be changed. This means, that c does no longer point to `A.Items[0]` but `A.Items[0]` is unaffected by this change.

Comment: @Mihaeru, yes I understand. I'm curious if there a way to replace pointer of all references by new pointer and seem like it illegal

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such way with C#. I guess you don't want to switch to C++ for this but there you could do that :)

Comment: @NamViNguyen There are no "Pointers" in the C/C++ sense in managed C#/.Net. But you also don't need them here. What I am suspecting is a x-y-question. What is the actual requirement you are trying to fulfill?